# How to move icon in primeng accordion from left to right?

Tags: css, angular, primeng, accordion

I want to use an accordion from PrimeNg and I want collapse icon to be on the right side, not left. I tried to manipulate the iconPos attribute, but I cannot make it working for me. Can someone advise me here?

```
<p-accordion [multiple]="true" [iconPos]="endVal"> // endVal comes from ts and gets "end"
   <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
       Content 1
   </p-accordionTab>
   <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
       Content 2
   </p-accordionTab>
   <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
       Content 3    
   </p-accordionTab>
 </p-accordion>
```

Comment: https://jake.stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-accordion-demo-fhmdta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

The `iconPos` parameter was introduced in PrimeNG 15.1.0, please make sure you're running at least this version.

Additionally, since this is a problem in your StackBlitz, please ensure you bind parameter to the property, not string 'endVal':

```html
<!-- in your StackBlitz -->
<p-accordionTab header="Header I" [selected]="true" iconPos="endVal">
<!-- should be -->
<p-accordionTab header="Header I" [selected]="true" [iconPos]="endVal">
```

[Demo](https://jake.stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-accordion-demo-3g7ldf)